# Parsing complex XML in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, parsing

I have an  XML and I want to print all his nodes and I want to access the movie nodes fields.

I can access Name and City, but I can`t access Movie fields.

```
<OnlineCinema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Cinema.xsd">
<Cinema>
    <City>Cluj</City>
    <Name>Cinema2</Name>
    <MovieName>ScaryMovie</MovieName>
    <Movie>
        <Name>ScaryMovie</Name>
        <Genre>comedie</Genre>
        <Director>lala</Director>
        <Writer>asdf</Writer>
        <Cast>asdvvb</Cast>
        <Year>2010</Year>
        <Trailer>http://www.youtube.com/embed/RMDZ8M47j0I</Trailer>
        <NRLoc>400</NRLoc>
    </Movie>
</Cinema>
```

Code:

```
use XML::Simple;
use Data::Dumper;

$xml = new XML::Simple (KeyAttr=>[]);
$data = $xml->XMLin("OnlineCinema.xml");
print "Content-type: text/html \n\n";

foreach $e (@{$data->{Cinema}}) {
    print "City: ", $e->{City}, "</br>\n";
    print "Name: ", $e->{Name}, "</br>\n"; 
    print "</br></br>\n";
}
```

Comment: XML::Simple is not recommended, perhaps try something XML::Parser based would be better.

Answer (score 3):

XML::Simple is the hardest XML parser to use. I use XML::LibXML.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file('OnlineCinema.xml');

for my $cinema ($doc->findnodes('/OnlineCinema/Cinema')) {
   my $cinema_name = $cinema->find('Name');
   my $cinema_city = $cinema->find('City');

   for my $movie ($cinema->findnodes('Movie')) {
      my $movie_name  = $movie->find('Name');
      my $movie_genre = $movie->find('Genre');

      print("$movie_name ($movie_genre) is playing at the $cinema_name in $cinema_city\n");
   }
}
```

(I assumed a *Cinema* can have more than one *Movie*, but given the presence of *MovieName* in *Cinema*, that might not be the case. It'll still work if it's not the case, but you might want to eliminate the inner `for` loop.)

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
use XML::Simple qw(:strict);
use Data::Dumper;

$xml = new XML::Simple (KeyAttr => [], ForceArray => [qw( Cinema )]);
$data = $xml->XMLin("OnlineCinema.xml");

print "Content-type: text/html \n\n";

foreach $e (@{$data->{Cinema}}) {
    print "City: ", $e->{City}, "<br/>\n";
    print "Name: ", $e->{Name}, "<br/>\n"; 
    print "<br/><br/>\n";
}
```

Basically, you are asking to go through the array of `Cinema` entries in your xml, but in this instance, since there's only one of them, it is built as a single scalar value. The `ForceArray` option tells the libray to consider that entry as a one element array, or more precisely, for any xml fed to the script, the `Cinema` tag(s) will always be made as an array of tags, whether there's one or more of them. That option may take:

- an array of tag names which must be forced to arrays,
- `1` to force it to all tags,
- `0` to not use it (which is the default)

Oh, and add a closing `OnlineCinema` tag at the end of your xml to have it parsed correctly.