# How to read from specific line to another line - Perl

Tags: regex, perl, readline

I'm doing a Perl script and I have a log file where I need to extract data from. I want to know how to read from a specific line to another line(not end of file).

I tried it this way by putting a `last if` if it reaches the line that I want to stop at but it doesn't work. The line that I want to start reading from is `<TEST_HEAD TH 1>` and stops at `</TEST_HEAD TH 1>`. I'm doing this because my regular expression captures data that I do not need, so I tried to read from a specific line to another line.

This is what I've done so far:

```
while(<$log_fh>)
{
    if($. =~ /\<TEST_HEAD TH 1\>/)
    {
      if ( /Computer Name:\s*(\S+)(-\d+)/i )
      {
          $details{tester_name} = $1 . $2;
          $details{tester_type} = $1;
          push @{$details{tester_arr}}, $1 . $2;
      }
      elsif ( /Operating System:\s*(.*\S)/i )
      {
          $details{op_sys} = $1;
      }
      elsif ( /IG-XL Version:\s*([^;]*)/i )
      {
          $details{igxl_vn} = $1;
      }
      elsif ( /^([\d]+)\.\d\s+(\S+)\s+([\d-]*)\s+([\d|\w]*)(?=\s)/ )
      {
          push @{$details{slot}}, $1;
          push @{$details{board_name}},  $2;
          push @{$details{part_no}},  $3;
          push @{$details{serial_no}},  $4;
      }
      last if $. == /\<\/TEST_HEAD TH 1\>/;
    }
}
```

Just a modified sample of the raw data file:

```
<TEST_HEAD TH 1> #Start reading here

    (Lines containing data to be captured)

</TEST_HEAD TH 1> #end reading here
```

Comment: `$.` => current file line number. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html

Comment: @Сухой27 Ohh I just saw the link. What should I use if I want to stop at the that line?

Comment: This looks like XML. It it?  If so, the solution may be even easier

Comment: @Sobrique It's not, I found a solution. I removed the `if` condition and added a `last if /^\<\/TEST\_HEAD TH 1\>/;` at the end of the last `elsif` after the curly bracket. Do you think I if it's possible if I put another `if` condition containing another regex after that? Because I still want to read some lines in another line. Or should I make a new while loop for `<$log_fh>`?

Comment: @Сухой27 How big is the input file? (e.g. less than 200KB) For small files the easiest option may be to slurp whole file into variable and extract the records from the scalar variable.

Comment: @Сухой27 The files are about 8MB each so I guess that would be out of the option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without going much into the nested matching logic you may want to change

```
if($. =~ /\<TEST_HEAD TH 1\>/)
```

into

```
if (/<TEST_HEAD TH 1>/ .. /<\/TEST_HEAD TH 1>/)
```

What you ask is actually XY problem and it would be better to process xml like document with xml parser. [Parsing complex XML in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268188/parsing-complex-xml-in-perl)

Comment: Hmm but only those two lines (and maybe a few, too many lines to point out from) are in that format, the rest are in plain text. Would the whole file be considered as a XML like document? And for the nesting logic it's alright, that's just for capturing data on the lines I want.

Comment: I tried your answer, it gives me a `Use of uninitialized value $_ in concatenation (.) or string at ...`

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing specifically how your data looks, I'd also offer another approach.

Set `$/` to a record separator, and then you grab a chunk of text in one go. You can then apply a bunch of different regexes to it all at once.

E.g.:

```
local $/ = 'TEST_HEAD';

while (<$log_fh>) {
    next unless m/^\s*TH/;

    my ( $tester_name, $tester_id ) = (m/Computer Name:\s*(\S+)(-\d+)/i);
    my ($op_sys) = (m/Operating System:\s*(.*\S)/i);
    my ( $slot, $board, $part, $serial ) =
        (m/^([\d]+)\.\d\s+(\S+)\s+([\d-]*)\s+([\d|\w]*)(?=\s)/m);

    # etc.

    # then validate and update your array:
    $details{$tester_name} = $tester_name;
    ## etc.
}
```